# How to control start and stop of fluid simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

How do you control when the fluid animation starts and stops? Because I want it to start a couple seconds in and then stop a few seconds later.

Comment: Can you maybe clarify your question? Poesibly with Screenshots? Do you mean start/stop in time or in space?

Answer (score 0):

Animate the Fluid's **Enabled** property by inserting Keyframes.

[image]

Comment: if I do this then there is a huge box where the domain is with the water materials on it when it isn't enabled that I can't get rid of. @J.Doe